# How to define a custom function in sympy?

Tags: function, sympy

I would define in Sympy a function like the following:

[image: Example of custom function]

f = x for x>=0
and
f = 1/x**2 for x<0

I tried to implement a custom function like the following:

```
class CustomFunction(Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, arg):
        arg = sympify(arg)
        if arg.is_number:
            if arg>=0:
                return ((x).subs(x,arg))
            else:
                return (1/x**2).subs(x, arg)

        if isinstance(arg, exp): 
            # What do I have to write here?
            pass
```

I would plot this function, and use it like any other function in sympy.
Please, could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You can do this with Piecewise

Comment: Great! It is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for your quick reply!